# Custom Ribbon in VSTO Addin for Outlook 2010 doesn't display

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, ribbon

I've got a minimal VSTO Addin for Outlook 2010 with a ribbon. My only goal is to display a ribbon (created via designer) with no functionality. From what little I can tell from MSDN ribbons should just automatically be displayed by default, perhaps with tweaking ControlIdType/CustomId properties for tabs.

Alas, tweaking these properties does nothing -- Outlook loads and displays no tab. A simple message box displayed in the ribbon loader reveals it never is triggered. Additionally, I haven't seen any information resources (tutorials, walkthroughs, overviews, etc..) that say anything about needing to manually tell Outlook to display tabs.

1. How do I get the tabs displayed?
2. Is there a good resource other than MSDN that's good for VSTO newbies?

Comment: The VSTO walk-thru that creates 'your first custom ribbon' for Excel 2013 produces this same problem - tab doesn't display. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386104.aspx

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To get your ribbon displayed, on the base ribbon in your code change the `RibbonType` property to be `Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the this answer. Spent hours on this. Why the official Microsoft examples and tutorials doesn't mention this, is out of my understanding.

Comment: Just for others reference this is found within the `<ribbon name>.Designer.cs` file within the region "Component Designer generated code".  Towards the end.

Comment: This answer is old but I'd like to note that this change didn't solve my simmilar problem using outlook 2010. I'll try creating a new project from scratch and report back here.

Comment: I'm back and IT WORKED. If you are having this issue try creating a fresh project add a ribbon file and make this minor change. Cheers!

Comment: This same fix worked for me using the Visual Studio 2015 and a Outlook 2013 Addin

Answer (score 2):

What fixed it for me (without starting a new project), in the Ribbon1.vb ribbon design, I clicked on the the Ribbon1 name above the ribbons 'File' button, in the properties pane, clicked on tabs (collection), under the heading 'Design' I changed the name (from Tab1) to something else.

Clicked ok, tested by clicking F5 and it worked. Hope this helps someone else.