# C#: Excel addin ribbon tab not displayed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, c#-4.0, ribbon

**Problem:** I have an Excel 2010 Add-In Project in Visual Studio 2010. I added a Ribbon (Visual Designer) in it but while debugging the custom tab is not showing up in Excel Ribbon.

**I have already tried all these:**

1. Creating a different project (*as I thought something might have broken this project*) but nothing --- same situation. [*ref*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567934/excel-add-ins-custom-ribbon-tab-will-not-display/)
2. Changing ControlIdType = Custom, ControlID="tabPsycho".
3. Checked Add-In option in Excel [*it does show in Active Application Add-Ins list*] and is checked. [*ref*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382904/excel-add-in-visibility)
4. Yes, it does load in Excel [*as I placed a Msgbox to check*]

Comment: Point 3. Remove the Add-In from Excel and build it again. Has happened to me in the past.

Comment: @SiddharthRout : Nope! Did it right now! no avail. :(

Comment: how did you remove it exactly?

Comment: @SiddharthRout : From Excel COM Add-In Manager :  Unchecked it & Removed it .. then In VS2010 - Rebuild the project & ran it.

Comment: I've the exact same problem with a Ribbon XML tag in my VSTO 2015 WORD addin. It was working before but the tag does not show anymore. I've tried all the suggestions from the above users in this post.

Answer (score 1):

Your add-in i probably disabled so enable it. If it is, here is the way to do it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: The Disabled items list is empty

Comment: That answer helped me. Here is a more up to date link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871(v=vs.140).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me in Visual Studio 2022, what you can try is the Build -> Rebuild Solution (and Rebuild All if prompted).

The add-in was getting loaded but not displayed in the Ribbon, and this took care of it.