# Outlook 2010 VSTO AddIn tab customization not showing

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

So i'm experimenting with creating a VSTO Outlook 2010 addin.
I'm following the instructions at this link:
**msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608593(v=vs.100).aspx**
to add a group to an existing tab. In this particular case I'm trying to add it to "TabMail" (control id obtained form the OutlookExplorerControls.xlsx file) which I got from this link: **go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=181052**.

The new group does not show up. Also the Outlook ribbon does not have an Add-ins tab.

I tried the same method for adding a group to an existing tab to Excel 2010 and it worked fine.

Here's my Outlook addin code (I made sure to set the build target to x86 as Office is 32 bit):
[Visual Studio snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIMdH.jpg)

The addin isn't crashing or being disabled.
[Screenshot shows the Outlook debug instance (with the addin options in the foreground)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWh9a.jpg)

The reg key at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\AddIns\OutlookAddIn1 look ok.

If anyone has any ideas, I'm all ears. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300526/custom-ribbon-in-vsto-addin-for-outlook-2010-doesnt-display/9300805#9300805

Comment: I tried it. It worked. Thanks!