# Outlook refuses to display customized ribbon

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins, ribbonx

My situation is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9300526/722393), but neither of the answers there worked for me.

In a brand-new project with no code, I have a very simple ribbon button:

[image]

...but Outlook (latest version, M365) will no longer display it. I say "no longer" because at first it did. I then removed it manually by Customizing the Ribbon and removing the custom group from the right-hand list:

[image]

Apparently, however, I should have removed it via the `File\Options\Add-ins` dialog, as it now won't display at all, no matter what I do. Oddly, the stock `Add-ins\Get Add-ins` combo flickers ever so slightly when I F5 run the project with Visual Studio (2022).

The more common solutions don't work. Web searches turn up answers to every problem but this one. ChatGPT is AWOL, presumably out trying to catch Rosie the Robot.

How do I get my button (and group) to show up again?

**--EDIT--**

I have since discovered that the ribbon does at least attempt to load when I start a new email message (but only the first time after I restart Outlook).

After turning on `Show VSTO Add-in user interface errors` in the Advanced options, I get this:

[image]

I tried renaming the tab in the designer to `TabMail`, but that didn't bring any improvement.

Here're the Properties for the `RibbonTab`:

[image]

...and here're my selected `RibbonTypes`:

[image]
[image]

Out of sheer curiosity I turned on the `StartFromScratch` property, and my button *does* display without error under that configuration:

[image]

I can also start a new email (using `Ctrl+N`) without the previous error message.

Here's the XML from my [ribbon export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-export-a-ribbon-from-the-ribbon-designer-to-ribbon-xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabAddIns">
        <group id="Group1" label="Group1">
          <button id="Button1" label="Click Me" showImage="false" />
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

After wiring up the `Override` in the new `Ribbon.vb`, there's no improvement in the overall situation when I use an XML ribbon vs. the ribbon designer.

Is my Outlook setup broken somehow? It sure feels like it.

Comment: Do you see the `Add-ins` tab on the ribbon?

Comment: I don't, no. I do, however, have an `Add-ins` _group_, as indicated in the second screenshot. My button first appeared just to the right of that.

Comment: From the screenshot it is not clear what settings you have for the `RibbonTab`.

Comment: I see that your custom UI should be added to the default tab in Outlook. Try to place it in a custom one.

Comment: I put it in a custom tab just now, and it works. All is well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, try to unregister and then register the add-in back by running the `Clean` command of your add-in project and then `Build` to register it back.

By default, if a VSTO Add-in attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom ribbon does not appear, or why a ribbon appears but no controls appear. For Outlook, the `Show VSTO Add-in user interface errors` checkbox is located in the `Developer` section of the details pane.

There are two ways of creating a custom ribbon UI with VSTO:

1. [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using the Ribbon Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-the-ribbon-designer?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp)
2. [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp)

Second, if you use the ribbon designer you need to check whether the `Add-ins` tab is visible on the ribbon or not. So, you may try to place your controls to the custom tab. Just click on the right hand side of your ribbon tab on the designer surface to add a custom tab. Also you may try to change ribbon controls IDs.

The last resort is to export your custom ribbon UI to the ribbon XML and troubleshoot the UI using callbacks. See [How to: Export a ribbon from the Ribbon Designer to Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-export-a-ribbon-from-the-ribbon-designer-to-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for having a look. I've edited my question to include the additional troubleshooting steps that you've advised. Alas, still no improvement.

Comment: What's the difference between removing an Add-in via the `File\Options\Add-ins` dialog and removing it by right-clicking the ribbon and choosing `Customize the Ribbon`? Did I send my setup sideways by opting for the latter by mistake?

Comment: In case of ribbon only the custom UI is removed, but the add-in continue its work.

Comment: Well, duh. I've been looking for my custom control on the `Home` tab. As I recall, you specifically asked me whether I had an `Add-ins` tab, and I said _no_. Wish I hadn't, 'cause I do. So my control is displaying and functioning correctly. Thank you.

Comment: _"the add-in continue its work"_ Yes, I just discovered that by starting a new email (and reproducing the error), and then right-clicking to customize the ribbon. There was an empty Add-ins group there, so I removed it. I restarted Outlook, started a new email, and the error was gone.

Comment: Observation: this thing sure is quirky.